# Отправить на сервер изображение с другими полями в JSON

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Получаю изображение неявным интентом из галереи и пока устанавливаю в ImageView(bitmap). Нужно передать JSON с полями на сервер, одно из которых ссылка на изображение. Использую Retrofit2. Читал что-то про отдельную загрузку изображений. Есть соображения по этому поводу. Отправлять на сервер изображение(пользователю проигрывать ProgressBar), получить в ответ путь до расположения на сервере, и с этим результатом уже отправлять финальный JSON. Что-то такое уже возвращать на сервер.

```
"results": [{
            "id": 1,
            "title": "YOUR TITLE 1",
            "type": "YOUR TYPE 1",                
            "picture": "http://myhost.ru/media/%D00%A3.jpg"
        }]
```

---

```
val file = File(path.path)
val requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file)
val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.name, requestFile)
```

---

```
@Multipart
@POST("endpoint/")
fun uploadPicture(@Part picture: MultipartBody.Part): Single<Any?>
```

Comment: насколько я понял, вопрос: как отправть JSON на сервер с помощью Retrofit2?

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев как отправить изображение на сервер совместно с другими полями.

Comment: Проблема не сформулирована, потому что в вопросе все расписано, и все верно: отправляете файл, добавляете путь в json, отправляете json. В такой последовательности.